# Missing word/numbering.xml in OOXML when retrieving bodyOOXML.value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ms-office, openxml, office-js, office-2016

When using JavaScript to get the OOXML body (bodyOOXML.value) as a string using the following code, the word/numbering.xml package is not included:

```
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Create a proxy object for the document body.
    var body = context.document.body;

    // Queue a commmand to get the OOXML contents of the body.
    var bodyOOXML = body.getOoxml();

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log("Body OOXML contents: " + bodyOOXML.value);
    });  
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

The word/styles.xml, word/fontTable.xml, etc. are included but without the numbering package we cannot recreate the number formats. Any help appreciated!

Comment: FWIW a couple of months ago I was trying to change number formats using Range.WordOpenXML and Word wouldn't accept anything I did if it was linked to a style. MS confirmed this is a limitation of WordOpenXML when the document is open in the application interface.  So if that's what you have in mind your question may be moot.

Comment: Jacqueline, great question! can you briefly explain your scenario? is this about getting the numbering format of a list?

FYI in the next wave of the API we will provide programmatic access to lists. and that includes getting the numbering format for numbered lists.

Please let me know! thanks!!! Juan.

Comment: Thanks for the response Juan! Yes, we need to access the numbering formats, as well as the bullet format for bulleted list. We would also need to be able to add list numbering to the word/numbering.xml package. Do you think this functionality would be made available as well? Fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 0):

This is problem because the office was 2016 when upgrade it to 2019 the problem has been solved

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment.